# Count Regular expression in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

I have to find how many numbers in the following String,

'~1~~2~~123~~~~12~~1~~~~' and the output should be 5.

Any help?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this in MySQL. Can you do it on the application layer?

Comment: Use a UDF that implements REGEXP_REPLACE (see http://stackoverflow.com/q/986826/18771) and then replace `\b\d` with `''`. The length difference difference between the original and the replaced string is your number.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL cannot do that directly. You would have to dig into UDF (User defined functions). It would allow you to create a function that returns the number of number substrings in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression need pattern to match and  there no pattern to use regular expression in provided example. You can go [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) to see regular expression in mysql.